# Python RotatingFileHandler not writing all results where FileHandler does

Tags: python, logging, rotation, handler

I have noticed that when I use the RotatingFileHandler not all of the events sent to the logger are written.

If I change to FileHandler, everything gets written.

If I set my handler like this:

```py
cjson_handler = RotatingFileHandler('{}/cjson.log'.format(log_directory), maxBytes=1024, backupCount=2)
```

Only the first event from the below code is written to the log file.

```py
    cjson_logger.info("system_info", extra={"CPU":cpu_details, "ROOT_USERS": users})
    core_list_small = core_list[:int(len(core_list) / 2)]
    cjson_logger.info("system_info", extra={"CPU": cpu_details_small, "ROOT_USERS": users})
```

If I change to:

```py
cjson_handler = logging.FileHandler('{}/cjson.log'.format(log_directory))
```

Both events are written. Both events are using the same handler, but do happen very close to each other.  Does this have something to do with the way rotating writes to the log versus the file handler?

Is there something different I need to do when writing multiple events to log with rotating handler?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `backupCount` non-zero, there will be `cjson.log.1` and `cjson.log.2` being created if `cjson.log` exceed `maxBytes`. I suspect your log message exceeded and another message was stored in `.1` or `.2` file.

However more info about your format, what your `extra` dict looks like and how do your deal with `extra` needed to make sure.